# Redirect into react-router from express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I'm adding authentication into my app, which uses react-router.And react router is handling my login/signup page.Also I'm using passport for authentication and passport authentication is working fine.

But I do experience a problem using this when my passport has a successful authentication and I'm redirecting to my dashboard page.

**server.js:-**

```
app.get('/auth/google/callback',
passport.authenticate('google', {
successRedirect: '/dashboard',
failureRedirect: '/',
 }));



 app.get('*',(req, res) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    webpackIsomorphicTools.refresh();
  }
  const memoryHistory = createHistory(req.originalUrl);
  const store=configureStore(memoryHistory);
  const history = syncHistoryWithStore(memoryHistory, store);

  function hydrateOnClient() {
    res.send(`<!doctype html>${ReactDOM.renderToString(<Default assets={webpackIsomorphicTools.assets()} store={store} />)}`);
  }

  match({ history, routes: routes(store), location: req.originalUrl },
  (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (redirectLocation) {
      res.redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    } else if (error) {
      console.error('ROUTER ERROR:', pretty.render(error));
      res.status(500);
      hydrateOnClient();
    } else if (renderProps) {
      const component = (
        <Provider store={store} key="provider">
          <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
        </Provider>
      );

      res.status(200);

      global.navigator = { userAgent: req.headers['user-agent'] };

      res.send(`<!doctype html>${ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup(<Default assets={webpackIsomorphicTools.assets()} component={component} store={store} />)}`);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Not found');
    }
  });
});
```

What's the best way to derive a URL on the server side to a dashboard route served by react-router?